# Creating\Editing BlueTooth SDP records

Tags: bluetooth, sdp

Do anybody know of any (free) tools that can aid in the creation\editing of Blue-Tooth's SDP (Service Discovery) records?

Windows based tools preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/) library.  There's no UI for this but there's library code which could be easily used for this.  Use class ServiceRecordBuilder. Some docs at [Creating Records](http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20Records). For example:

```c#
ServiceRecordBuilder bldr = new ServiceRecordBuilder();
bldr.AddServiceClass(BluetoothService.SerialPort);
bldr.ServiceName = "Alan's SPP service";
bldr.AddBluetoothProfileDescriptor(BluetoothService.AVRemoteControl, 1, 0);
bldr.AddCustomAttribute(new ServiceAttribute(0x8001,
    ServiceElement.CreateNumericalServiceElement(ElementType.UInt16, 0xFEDC)));
//
ServiceRecord record = bldr.ServiceRecord;
//
var txt = ServiceRecordUtilities.Dump(record);
Console.WriteLine(txt);
//
var byteArr = record.ToByteArray();
var txtBA = BitConverter.ToString(byteArr);
Console.WriteLine(txtBA);
```

Output is:

```
ElementSequence
    ElementSequence
        Uuid16: 0x100 -- L2CapProtocol
    ElementSequence
        Uuid16: 0x3 -- RFCommProtocol
        UInt8: 0x0
( ( L2Cap ), ( Rfcomm, ChannelNumber=0 ) )

AttrId: 0x0006 -- LanguageBaseAttributeIdList
ElementSequence
    UInt16: 0x656E
    UInt16: 0x6A
    UInt16: 0x100

AttrId: 0x0009 -- BluetoothProfileDescriptorList
ElementSequence
    ElementSequence
        Uuid16: 0x110E -- AVRemoteControl
        UInt16: 0x100

AttrId: 0x0100 -- ServiceName
TextString: [en] 'Alan's SPP service'

AttrId: 0x8001
UInt16: 0xFEDC
```

array:

```
35-51-09-00-01-35-03-19-11-01-09-00-04-35-0C-35-03-19-01-00-35-05-19-00-03-08-00-09-00-06-35-09-09-65-6E-09-00-6A-09-01-00-09-00-09-35-08-35-06-19-11-0E-09-01-00-09-01-00-25-12-41-6C-61-6E-27-73-20-53-50-50-20-73-65-72-76-69-63-65-09-80-01-09-FE-DC
```

Answer (score 0):

BlueZ is the linux Bluetooth stack, and it comes with sdptool utility for working with SDP.  This page has some examples, http://alanjmcf.wordpress.com/2011/08/09/bluez-sdptool-usage-notes/