# Bluetooth SDP structure

Tags: c, winapi, bluetooth, sdp

What's the structure of a SDP stream? I'm trying to add a new SDP bluetooth record in Windows 7, but I can't understand what's the "raw stream" contents. I know what I need to put there, I just don't know the format/protocol and google didn't helped me a lot this time.

It's to use with [IOCTL_BTH_SDP_SUBMIT_RECORD_WITH_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536694%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: See my answer at [Creating\Editing BlueTooth SDP records](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11862872/35049)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [Core Version 2.1 + EDR](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=241363), Vol. 3 Part B - SDP. I was looking at the SADP bluetooth profile, therefore the confusion and difficulty in finding it.